# Remove Re: AW: and other from subject in Mail

Tags: mail.app, email

Is there any possible way to avoid these long "Re: AW:"(and so on) in the subject field of Mail? I know that Thunderbird can replace e.g. *AW:* (that is the German version coming from Outlook) or *SV:* (Danish) with the proper *Re:*. Up to now, I could not find anything similar for Apple Mail.

Comment: Those German abbreviations _are_ annoying...

Comment: Its not just German. There is Danish and probably many others.

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm you may see my own answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a plugin for mail.app which does exactly that. You can find it at:[github](https://github.com/pgab/subjectREplace) feel free to use it.