# Remove "RE: " from Mac OS Mail subject line

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I have this annoying problem where when somebody responds to my email their mailer application adds "Re: " in front of the subject line and Mail can not group the messages in that thread.

Is there a way to delete "Re:" from all subject lines? There is this [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52391/remove-re-aw-and-other-from-subject-in-mail) from 2012 but I can't make that plugin work.

Comment: Mail clients usually use the `Message-Id` and `In-Reply-To` header fields to group messages, specifically because `Subject` fields are subject(!) to change. I would be surprised if they use the `Subject` fields at all, maybe only as a last resort, with intricate fuzzy logic and considerable chance of failure. Check the email headers for `Message-Id` and `In-Reply-To`. If they are present and match the other mails you expect to see grouped together, I would report a bug to Apple.

Comment: I went to check the messages raw source for a couple of threads, one that is grouped correctly and another that doesn't. The bad one does not have the In-Reply-To field. Both have a Message-Id field.

Comment: Did you check the **contents** of the fields? That's what matters. `In-Reply-To` contains a list of unique IDs. Messages with matching IDs should be grouped.